# Why mouseMoveEvent does nothing in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, events, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I try to use mouseMoveEvent and mousePressEvent in PyQt5 and Python3.5, but there is nothing when I click my mouse. My code is as following, is there something wrong?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        self.graphicsView.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.NoButton:
            print("Simple mouse motion")
        elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Left click drag")
        elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print("Right click drag")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Press!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you must enable [mouse-tracking](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop):

```
        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
```

Then you can either use a subclass of `QGraphicsView`:

```
class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):   
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.NoButton:
            print("Simple mouse motion")
        elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Left click drag")
        elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print("Right click drag")
        super(GraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Press!")
        super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```

Or install an event-filter:

```
        self.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        ...

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.NoButton:
                print("Simple mouse motion")
            elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                print("Left click drag")
            elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                print("Right click drag")
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                print("Press!")
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am sure that your events is handled inside `QGraphicsView`. You have to read more about event propagation. Try it without adding any additional widgets on top of Window. And do not forget abt MouseTracking property, which is false by default and mouse move events without buttons do not happend at all.

I would recomend to read [this](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation/) article. It's is quite old, but still relevant. Also mouse events in `QGraphicsView` handled in a different way, read [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssceneevent.html#details) for more details.

Sory no code samples since I am C++ developer.