# Catching events within QtDesigner generated widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm trying to make an app that would allow to manipulate some objects within QGraphicsView/QGraphicScene using the mouse (adding, moving, resizing, etc.). The UI is generated from QtDesigner.
All examples that I googled show that mouse events are handled from within main application class. However, if there are more widgets that deal with mouse events, I thought that it would be wise to keep the mouse logic within those widgets separately.
I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35995179/10836004) advice with separate class, but since my widgets are generated by designer, it doesn't seem to work.

My designer generated code:

```py
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.DesignWindowView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.DesignWindowView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 761, 501))
        self.DesignWindowView.setObjectName("DesignWindowView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 23))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Main file:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui, QtCore
from Ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class DesignWindowView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Press on DesignWindowView!")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("Mouse on DesignWindowView")

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        DesignWindowScene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        DesignWindowScene.addSimpleText("The Text")
        self.DesignWindowView.setScene(DesignWindowScene)
        self.DesignWindowView.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.DesignWindowView.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
# load MainWindow design
mainwindow = MainWindow()
# start the UI's event loop
app.exec_()
```

The DesignWindowView class would be responsible wor widget generated from QtDesigner, but this obviously doesn't work and none mouse events are catched.
I don't have any experience with OOP and I don't fully understand the concept of subclassing (as I think this is the way it should be done).

Comment: see https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/qt-creator/embed-pyqtgraph-custom-widgets-qt-app/

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading that now. I've seen it before but I haven't been aware what the custom widget really is, so I omitted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the events aren't caught is because in the .py file generated from the QtDesigner file, `self.DesignWindowView` is still a `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView` object. The solution to this is to promote the `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView` in Qt Designer to a `DesignerWindowView` object.

For this it's best to put the definition of `DesignerWindowView` in a separate `.py` file (e.g. `designerwindowview.py`) to prevent circular dependencies between the main `.py` file and the `.py` file generated from the QtDesigner file.

In designer, right-click on the widget that you want to promote and choose `Promote to ...`. Fill in the promoted class name (`DesignerWindowView`). For the name of the header file you should fill in the name of the .py file with the definition of the promoted class without the `.py` extension (e.g. `designerwindowview`).

Save and run through `pyuic5` as before. In the generated .py file  `self.DesignWindowView` should now be a `DesignWindowView` object, and there should be an import statement similar to `from designwindowview import DesignWindowView` at the bottom of the `.py` file.

Comment: Thank you! I've been googling for this solution around for about two days.